# Existance and uniqueness theorem Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential

If $f$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous in a rectangle $R: |t| \leq a, |y| \leq b,$ then there is some interval $|t| \leq h \leq a$ in which there exists a unique solution $y = \phi (t)$ of the initial value problem, $y^{'} = f(t,y)$

The book doesn't provide a proof of this theorem and I wanted to know why this is true. I know continuity implies that $\int f(t,y)$ exists but from there how do you show there is a smaller interval and or rectangle and that the solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

See  the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) (the general version has slightly weaker
hypotheses than yours)